# RxJava 2 - filter list inside list objects

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

`getData()` returns a **Single`<ArrayList1>`** which has alot of objects inside, that also are `ArrayListX`. I want to recieve only those `cars`(ArrayList) that is not empty. Of course, `results.filter { cars -> cars.size > 0 }` will not work, as it returns list not boolean. How to achieve this in correct manner? P.S. Still learning rxjava, haha

```
val disposable = repository.getData()
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .filter { results ->
                        results.filter { cars -> cars.size > 0 }
                    }
                    .subscribe({ searchResults ->
                       ...
                    }, { _ ->
                        ...
                    })
            compositeDisposable.add(disposable)
```

Comment: Use `map` instead of `filter` with RxJava.

Comment: as [@akarnokd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61158/akarnokd) said, you probably wanted: `.map { results -> results.filter { cars -> cars.size > 0 } }`

Comment: @akarnokd I edited post. I return `Single<Arraylist>`. I don't think I need `map` for that.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
import io.reactivex.Single
import java.util.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val source = Single.just(Arrays.asList(
            Collections.emptyList(),
            Arrays.asList(1, 2),
            Collections.emptyList(),
            Arrays.asList(3, 4, 5)
    ));

    // Single<List<(Mutable)List<Int!>!>!>!
    val output = source.map({ items -> items.filter({ !it.isEmpty()} )})

    output.subscribe({ res -> System.out.println(res) })
}
```

prints

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
```